# Calling two webservices at the same time using RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, restkit

Hello I am using Restkit for the first time and able to call the webservices properly but there is a situation where I have to call two webservices on one of my viewcontroller to get all the data required from the server
ex : I have one service which gives userProfile data and second I have to call for userLevelType

Right now I am calling first webservices which gives me  useprofile when I get that data I am calling second webservices userLevelType but I want to call both the services at one time

Is there any way to achieve calling two different web services at one time.

I am using RKobjectRequestOperation to call the webservices so is it possible to make a queue or some other solution which I am not aware of

Thanks for helping.

Comment: RestKit already has a queue. Show the code for how you are currently executing the request operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an object manager to control the request operations your handling. Use `enqueueObjectRequestOperation:` to pass handling over to the object manager. Access the `operationQueue` of the object manager so that you can call `setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:` to limit the number of concurrent processes running (you shouldn't really have more than 4 or 5 at any one time).

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with an async system which is hitting network based resources. "At the same time" is practically impossible.

`RestKit` will queue up the requests in the order that you give them.

If your requests are sequentially dependant you need to chain them together via the completion block like so.

```
RequestOperationSucessBlock successblock = ^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult){

        [self runNextRequestWhichIsDependantOnDataFromThisRequest];

    };

RequestOperationFailBlock failureblock = ^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation,  NSError *error){

        //deal with failure

    };


[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"my/path" parameters:someParams success:successblock failure:failureblock];
```

If they are not dependant, use a conditional in both success blocks to move ahead in your flow.

```
RequestOperationSucessBlock successblock = ^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult){

        if(theOtherOperationHasCompleted) {

           [self carryOnWithFlowNowThatBothOperationsAreDone];
        }

    };
```

Comment: This isn't really truer. Computers multitask all the time. The OP is also using the RK operations directly rather than using an object manager.

Comment: True , ios does multitask. But likelyhood of receiving two independent network calls back simultaneously is very small. OP shouldn't rely on that happening. In reality between 0 & 2 responses will be got.

Comment: Better described as: the requests can run concurrently instead of sequentially, but don't rely on anything about when each will finish. RestKit won't queue the requests to finish in the same order that they are made (unless you configure it to).